# Convert HTTPDATE timestamp to correct format in Graylog

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, format, filebeat, graylog3

I have Squid writing logs with a timestamp as dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss ZZZZ

"27/Jul/2022:11:55:40 +0100"

I'm sending these logs into Graylog using Filebeat, then parsing the timestamp into individual fields using HTTPDATE in a Grok extractor, so I can get separate Month, Monthday, Year etc fields.

I need to replace the "message received" @timestamp field with the actual "event occurred" timestamp when the event is indexed in Elasticsearch.

How can I convert the Squid timestamp from HTTPDATE into yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format?

"2022-07-27 11:55:40"

Thanks

---

EDIT:

Actually I think I have this now. In case it helps anyone else, this was done with a Regex Replacement Extractor:

[Extractor Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdcLw.png)

[Extractor Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O21wY.png)

[Extractor Part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TQ1m.png)

Answer (score -1):

This is an excellent question for the community. Try it there.